# much different time in executing a query for first time

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which I ran on my server, I used SSMS for this action then I use Live Query Statistics.

In the middle of running first query, I copied query and ran it in parallel with my first query, unexpectedly it took about 25 seconds to be done but my first query still was running for about 10 minutes.

Beside the difference between execution time, SSMS live query shown with about 9 minutes delay in my first query.

Why I got that large difference in execution time? Some sort of blocking?

**SQL SERVER : SQL SERVER 2016 core-based.

Windows Server : 2016.

SSMS : 2016.**

Comment: Are you saying you were running the Live Query Statistics on one, while not on the other? That **will** have an effect on the speed of the query; as the query is being analysed as it runs (thus slowing it down).

Comment: No I used it for both .